# What is better to use? (px or %)

Tags: html, css, width, percentage

I just wanted to ask, because I am new to web design, is it better for width to use `px` or `%`?

I am asking this because I am working on website and when I put all in one container with, for example, `1348px width`, and use `px` for all other `divs` inside and then zoom in or zoom out my site, everything is ok, but if I put `%` for `width`, on zoom isn't everything good, but I had read that `%` is better because of responsive web design.

So because of that I want to know what is better to use, and if we use `%` how to avoid getting my website falling apart on zoom in or zoom out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By and large, it is good practice to use responsive values for most values. Relative units such as %, rem, em, vh, vw, are some examples.

the philosophy behind this is that you want the website to fluidly adapt to whatever viewport it loads in, whether a phone, tablet, or varying monitor sizes. the problem with static elements like px, is that they are inherently fixed values. Things like media queries and breakpoints can give you a little responsiveness with pixels, but its just best practice to use responsive units.

It'll make your life easier.

Comment: So it is better to use %, and then to use media queries for different screen sizes, if I understood correctly.

Comment: Yes, if you aren't using a responsive CSS framework such as Bootstrap or Foundation, using media queries in conjunction with units such as % will (if written correct), result in better optimized code. 

I think it's safe to say that if possible, use relative units over px